# Javascript - Show/change image on hover

Tags: javascript, image, html-table

I have a table on one side and an area for an image on the right.
When a row within the table is hovered over, I want a different image to display.
There will end up being 20 rows of data, with 20 respective images.

I have javascript:

```
document.getElementById("showlot1").mouseover = function() {
document.getElementById("lot1").style.visibility = "visible"; }

document.getElementById("showlot2").mouseover = function() {
document.getElementById("lot2").style.visibility = "visible"; }
```

CSS:

```
#lot1, #lot2 { visibility: hidden; }
```

HTML Table:

```
<table style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="2">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="hover">
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <a id="showlot1">1</a>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <a id="showlot1">3.4ha (8.4 acres)</a>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <a id="showlot1"></a>$99,000</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hover">
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <a id="showlot2">2</a>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <a id="showlot2">3.5ha (8.6 acres)</a>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <a id="showlot2">$99,000</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

HTML Image Placer:

```
<img id="lot1" src="/wp-content/uploads/sites/291/2015/02/QA-CONTOUR-LOT1.jpg" />
<img id="lot2" src="/wp-content/uploads/sites/291/2015/02/QA-CONTOUR-LOT2.jpg" />
```

Comment: IDs can only be use once and `"lot1, lot 2"` is an invalid selector, for gEBI you must select them invididually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I found using classes to denote functional elements easier; a bunch of elements with `id`s (which is illegal by the way, as `id`'s should be unique in the document) I changed to putting a class `.showImage` on your `tr`'s and targeting them with event listeners.
2. I used CSS to set images to `display:none;` by default. This is more ideal than `visibility:hidden` because they disappear completely and won't take up space.
3. Instead of using anonymous functions, I split the desired result into two `mouseover` and `mouseout` handlers that toggle the display property. You'll see they also take a parameter `index`, which I used to determine which `#lot` to target:

`function showImageOnMouseover(i) {<change display property to block>}`
and
`function hideImageOnMouseout(i) {<change display property to none>}`

Where `i` is a variable used to find the right image using your convention `#lot<i>`

```js
// get elements by class name
var elementSelection = document.getElementsByClassName('showImage');

// attach event listener to each element
for( var i=0; i<elementSelection.length; i++ ) {
 elementSelection[i].addEventListener( 'mouseover', showImageOnMouseover(i+1) );
  // pass i+1 to index since i starts out as 0. You could just as easily change the for loop to var i=1, or alter your #lot naming convention to start at 0.
  elementSelection[i].addEventListener( 'mouseout', hideImageOnMouseout(i+1) );
}

// handle mouseover
function showImageOnMouseover( index ) {
 return function(e) {
   var imgId = 'lot' + index.toString();
    console.log(imgId);
    document.getElementById( imgId ).style = ( 'display: block' );
  }
}

// handle mouseout
function hideImageOnMouseout( index ) {
  return function(e) {
      var imgId = 'lot' + index.toString();
      document.getElementById( imgId ).style = ( 'display: none' );
  }
}
```

```css
#lot1 {
  display: none;
}

#lot2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%;">
 <tbody>
  <tr class="hover showImage">
   <td style="text-align: center;">
    <a>1</a>
   </td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">
    <a>3.4ha (8.4 acres)</a>
   </td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">
    <a></a>$99,000
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hover showImage">
   <td style="text-align: center;">
    <a>2</a>
   </td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">
    <a>3.5ha (8.6 acres)</a>
   </td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">
    <a>$99,000</a>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<img id="lot1" src="http://www.kaybojesen.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/505-Dessertske-ni-tre.png" />
<img id="lot2" src="https://www.house.com.au/images/hires/HAG-CU249610.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple way would be to do it with css.

**HTML**

```
<img id="myimg" src="first_image"/>
```

**CSS**

```
#myimg:hover {
    content: url('second_image');
}
```

See running JSFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/nepxx02a/2/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am going to end up with 20 images (20 rows of data).

Comment: Wow, nice and simple! +1